# Complex integral of $\frac{1}{it - A}$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Let $A,B \in \mathbb R^+$, how can I evaluate or give a rough upper bound for the integral $$\int_{B}^{-B}\frac{1}{it - A}dt$$

I looked at it in wolfram alpha and it has a complex log which I would like to avoid if possible. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

$$\frac{1}{it-A}=\frac{-A}{A^2+t^2}-i\frac{t}{A^2+t^2}.$$
So you can write the integral in function of $\ln$ and $\arctan$.

Comment: The first part does not make much sense and it is misleading. I think you should delete that part.

Comment: Why $\int_{-B}^B \frac{1}{it+A}dt=\frac{1}{i}\ln(it-A)$ doesn't make sense for you ? As far as I know, this is true... @KaviRamaMurthy

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\left.\int_{B}^{-B}{1 \over \ic t - A}\,\dd t
\,\right\vert_{\ A, B\ \in\ \mathbb{R}}} =
-\int_{-B}^{B}{-\ic t - A \over t^{2} + A^{2}}\,\dd t =
2A\int_{0}^{B}{\dd t \over t^{2} + A^{2}}
\\[5mm] = &\
2A\,{1 \over A^{2}}\,\verts{A}\int_{0}^{B}{\dd t/\verts{A} \over \pars{t/\verts{A}}^{2} + 1} =
2\,\mrm{sgn}\pars{A}\int_{0}^{B/\verts{A}}{\dd t \over t^{2} + 1}
\\[5mm] = &\
2\,\mrm{sgn}\pars{A}\arctan\pars{B \over \verts{A}} =
\bbx{2\arctan\pars{B \over A}} \\ &
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you this is great!

Comment: @rain1 You’re welcome.